# Not able to set 'access-control-allow-credentials' response header in aws serverless lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless, response-headers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugyig.png)

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true not set even after sending it in response headers from serverless.yml lambda function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6ziQ.png)
Have added response headers as below, in lambda function but it's not setting.

`- http:

> ```
>   path: /path
> ```

```
    method: post
    authorizer: ${self:custom.authorizer}
    cors:
      origins: 
        - http://localhost:8080
        - http://localhost:8081
      headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}
      allowCredentials: true
    response:
      headers:
        Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "'true'"`
```

I am implementing cookie here, hence for that i set multiple origins which is working fine and inorder to access cookie i need access-control-allow-credentials to be set true in response headers of options API. I don't want to set this header from Api-Gateway AWS management console, i need to set it from code and found the reference from below serverless docs. But the response header is not being set by above code in OPTIONS API.

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#custom-response-headers

{self.custom.allowedHeaders} : Content-Type, authorization, language

This above header is set in response 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' of normal POST/GET request and also in the option request and is also displayed in API gateway. Please check below image for same.
[API Gateway Options API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4UpL.png)

In image above you can also see the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header set to true manually there by me. But my question here is how can i add the header there with any change in above code of lambda function (Serverless.yml) file.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Could you please create an MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we could try and reproduce your problem.  Thank you!

Comment: Can you share your custom.allowedHeaders here?
You are not getting this header in your OPTIONS request, the only reason you're still facing cors is most probably because you haven't allowed this header.
`response:` has nothing to do with the OPTIONS request, that's all controlled by cors:

Comment: @HimanshuPant Have added headers and related image of API gateway in description above. Thank you!

Comment: @NaisargiTrivedi That's the bug right there, you aren't allowing `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`. That's why it's being filtered out and not being returned to the user. Try adding that to allowedHeaders